# How do you use Pandas to copy a cell value into a table in Word?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm trying to copy cell values from an excel file into table in a Word document but, I keep getting an error when it comes to equating a table cell with a cell value from an Excel file. I've tried a couple of things but keep getting an error

Attempt 1:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd


document = Document()
workbook = load_workbook(filename = r"C:\Users\Desktop\excel_file.xlsx")
sheet = workbook['Sheet2']

tries = 5
for i in range(1, tries + 1):  
    table = document.add_table(rows = 4, cols = 2, style = 'Table Grid')
    table.cell(0,0).text = "ACCT #"
    table.cell(1,0).text = "NAME"
    table.cell(0,1).text = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
    table.cell(1,1).text = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 2).value
```

This gives me
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'`

And it references this line:
`table.cell(0,1).text = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1).value`

Also, the data in the Excel file has numbers in the first column and names in the second column, just so you know. Not sure if this matters.

Attempt 2: Using Pandas

```
document = Document()
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Desktop\excel_file.xlsx",sheet_name = None, header = None)
data = df["Sheet2"]


tries = 5
for i in range(1, tries + 1):  
    table = document.add_table(rows = 4, cols = 2, style = 'Table Grid')
    table.cell(0,0).text = "ACCT #"
    table.cell(1,0).text = "NAME"
    table.cell(0,1).text = data.iloc[i, 0]
    table.cell(1,1).text = data.iloc[i, 1]
```

And this gives me: `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`
and it references: `table.cell(0,1).text = data.iloc[i, 0]`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it at this point. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd


def addTable(doc, df):
    doc.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
    tabrows = df.shape[0]
    tabcols =df.shape[1]
    table = doc.add_table(rows = tabrows+1, cols = tabcols, style= 'Table Grid')
    table.cell(0,0).text = "Account"
    table.cell(0,1).text = 'Name'
    for r in range(tabrows):
       for c in range(tabcols):
          table.cell(r+1,c).text = str(df.iloc[r,c])

    doc.add_page_break()

def main():
   dfin = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[1,2,3,4,5],'Words':['Alpha','Beta',
                       'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Epsilon']})
   doc = Document()
   addTable(doc, dfin)
   doc.save('tstdoc.docx')


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was actually able to figure it out before you replied. I just had to convert `data.iloc[i, 0]` into a string for it to work!

Comment: Can you post your solution and mark the question answered?